# Stay with current job or leave for better paying job?

Tags: salary, resignation, quitting, promotion

Good morning!

I'm computer science graduate and I would like to ask for your inputs regarding my current predicament.

I used to be a software engineer in an IT company. I was a functional support of a certain system. I left the company to pursue another career which was a programming career. I overestimated my optimism and thought I could easily land a new job but failed. I went freelance for one year. I know, I made a very wrong decision about this but I learned my lesson.

Now, I'm working as a database encoder (definitely a job mismatch since im in the medical department and doing a non-IT related work) in a healthcare company (current salary is about 25% lower) for about 3 months now. My Aunt is friends with my boss here so I couldn't reject the offer to work and I thought it's better to have a regular job (even if it pays lower than my previous job) than doing freelance work.

While I highly appreciate the way my boss takes care of me and her effort to build me up so I could move up the ladder and be promoted (she talked to me and told me that the president of the company is eyeing me to be the lead of a new business unit they are planning to create), my current pay is not really enough to get by smoothly. I couldn't have savings at all and literally live on an equivalent of $2/day. I want to apply for another IT company which will guarantee me at least a 50-75% increase in pay.

If you were in my place, would you stay in your current job with a small salary in hopes of having a higher pay once you get promoted and because your boss is making an effort to  build you up, or leave as soon as you land a new job in an IT company which definitely will pay higher?

Honestly, I don't really like my current job (i dont hate it too, it's just that I think I'd be happier working in an IT field) but what matters to me is the pay since I need money to live because I support my family (bills, food, and medication).

I am open to all sorts of opinion be it negative or positive.

Thank you so much!

EDIT:  I couldn't delete my post. Question already flagged for being Off-topic and asked mods for thread deletion or closure. thank you so much to all who commented! Will read rules next time prior to posting.

Comment: I'm sorry, but advice on what to do is off topic here.  We don't know your situation, or what your goals and aspirations are.  You should probably talk to friends or family who have a far better idea about you and your situation.

Comment: Yes, it's probably better to ask whether people think it's a good idea to ask for a raise after you've been working there for three months, or whether it's a good idea to move on to another job, then what we would do in your place.  We don't really know what your place is, as @JaneS aptly points out.

Comment: Oh, I'm really sorry. I should've read the rules first before asking this. I'm really sorry. I'll be closing this soon. Well basically my status is, I left my previous job because of a bad decision, Now I'm getting paid lower. But there is an opportunity for a better paying job. I guess my question should be, should i take the opportunity for a new job since it pays higher (i can support my family better) or stay here since my boss is making an effort to build me up despite having a currently low pay)?

Comment: Unfortunately that's still the same question.  It's asking what to do, which we can't answer for you.

Comment: Oh, too bad. I'll be deleting this thread. I'm sorry for not being compliant with the rules here. Anyway, Thank you so much Jane and Bob! I'll be reading some of the comments for a while then proceed with the deletion. :)

Comment: If you rephrase that to "what are some of the consequences of x, as opposed to y" I don't think you'll be off topic.  If you ask us to choose x or y for you, then you certainly will be.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't leave the company after three months, especially if you like it there and have an opportunity to advance.  Data encoding is not "non-IT-related work."  IT is all about data, and an intimate understanding of the data you are working with is essential to being able to do any sort of software design and/or engineering.  So, you have to get familiar with whatever medical coding standard your company is using, and you are doing precisely that.

Now, it's very important to keep in mind that in IT, sometimes you get to ride the horses, and sometimes you get to shovel out the stables.  No matter how high up you are in the organization.  If you are willing to do the latter as often as is necessary to keep things running in the right direction, you will become more and more valuable to the organization.  Right now, you are shoveling the stables.  If you put in two years and that's all you get to do, then maybe you need to find a job where you get to ride sometimes as well.  But not after three months.

You could find that higher-paying job, and two years from now feel even more stuck than you do now, so don't get the grass is greener on the other side of the fence problem.

You might have a chat with your boss, and see if you can get a better feel for what the job is that the president is eyeing you for.  I wouldn't discuss pay here even if it is your primary concern.  Rather, I would discuss your genuine interest and curiosity in what they want you to do.  You will probably have some input here as well, in particular if you can find ways that your boss's feedback about the new job description ties in with your own interests and ambitions.  If you can, then share those: "That sounds interesting.  I can see how that would give me the opportunity to do more of x, which is where my real passion lies."

If you really can't afford to work for what they're paying you, you might want to have a talk with your aunt in confidence, and see what she thinks about asking for a raise.  It seems awfully soon to me to be asking, but she may know more than I do, especially if it's a small company.  If she doesn't think you should ask this early, maybe (and I mean maybe, I don't know at all whether this will work for you on a personal level) you can go find a part-time job for a couple of nights in the week, and tell your boss that you had to take it to help pay the bills for a while, and you aren't able to stay late on Wednesdays or Fridays or whatever.  Then you're putting them on notice that you need to make more money, but you like working there so much that you're reluctant to look elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you so much Bob! This is really insightful. Maybe I should take a lil more time to think about this, and eventually decide on what I really want to do. And yeah, talk to my boss and aunt about this. I guess I've just gotten used to an actual technical work instead of doing Excel 8hrs/day. Not that im complaining though.

I'm deleting the thread for this is off topic. i saved your comment for future guidance. Thanks Bob!

Answer (score 1):

You already answered your own question. You would rather work in IT than this new field.

Long term the IT pay prospects are more. Job is easier and many things to learn.

And why is that they would make you the business head of an unit ? Do you have the necessary qualifications ? Worse thing i read is you got this job through some family  connection.

My suggestion go for the IT job.

Comment: That's exactly what happened. I got this because of my aunt which is friends with the boss here. all the time I am using excel, arranging data, comparing, etc. But since I have a programming background, I automate it which is what impresses them. And that's basically the only advantage i have over the seasoned employees here.

I'm leaning towards the IT opportunity. I hope it isnt unethical to leave a work for a new company despite my boss making an effort to make me the head of the new unit

Comment: Its is your life. If they fire you what you gonna do . You can and must decide the direction of your life. Get a better opportunity and leave ! your skills will be used and enhance better there than writing a bunch of excel macros.

Comment: Thank you! I guess I'm just too afraid to disappoint my aunt and her friend (my boss who is very looking forward with me being part of the company for good). I will definitely leave once given the opportunity. After all I signed a 3-6 months contract only.

Comment: Do not be afraid. Keep learning.